# constraining movements to a grid

Tags: javascript, p5.js, khan-academy

This is all of the code, you would have to access Khan academy's ProcessingJS library to get the rest of it.
My issue is that when you start a movement (using rmb), and then while the ellipse is moving start another movement, the ellipse can disconnect from the grid and it looks odd. I'm wondering how I can make it so that this does not happen, while still keeping the ability to overwrite a movement with another. Perhaps by making it move back to the center of its grid square before starting a new movement? but I have no idea HOW to make that happen.
if you were to start a new movement while the ellipse was not in the center of its current square it would continue moving, not at the center of any square until it reaches its location. I am looking to fix this.

```js
// var setup
// p is current player location
var pX = 210;
var pY = 210;
// m is movement target
var mX = 210;
var mY = 210;
// t is starting position
var tX = pX;
var tY = pY;
// s is p rounded to grid
var sX = 0;
var sY = 0;

// rounding numbers (used for grid)
function roundNum(number, increment, offset) {
    return Math.ceil((number - offset) / increment ) * increment + offset;
}

// mouse click
mouseClicked = function() {
    if(mouseButton===39 || mouseButton === 'left'){
        mX = roundNum(mouseX-10,20,10);
        mY = roundNum(mouseY-10,20,10);
        tX = sX;
        tY = sY;
    }
};

draw = function() {
    
    // draw setup
    background(255, 255, 255);
    sX = roundNum(pX,20,10);
    sY = roundNum(pY,20,10);
    
    
    // grid (perhaps find a way to simplify)
    stroke(0, 0, 0);
    fill(255, 255, 255);
       // vertical lines
       line(380,400,380,0);
       line(360,400,360,0);
       line(340,400,340,0);
       line(320,400,320,0);
       line(300,400,300,0);
       line(280,400,280,0);
       line(260,400,260,0);
       line(240,400,240,0);
       line(220,400,220,0);
       line(200,400,200,0);
       line(180,400,180,0);
       line(160,400,160,0);
       line(140,400,140,0);
       line(120,400,120,0);
       line(100,400,100,0);
       line(80,400,80,0);
       line(60,400,60,0);
       line(40,400,40,0);
       line(20,400,20,0);
       // horizontal lines
       line(0,20,400,20);
       line(0,40,400,40);
       line(0,60,400,60);
       line(0,80,400,80);
       line(0,100,400,100);
       line(0,120,400,120);
       line(0,140,400,140);
       line(0,160,400,160);
       line(0,180,400,180);
       line(0,200,400,200);
       line(0,220,400,220);
       line(0,240,400,240);
       line(0,260,400,260);
       line(0,280,400,280);
       line(0,300,400,300);
       line(0,320,400,320);
       line(0,340,400,340);
       line(0,360,400,360);
       line(0,380,400,380);
    
    // movement, hopefully.
    noStroke();
    fill(18, 235, 33);
    if(pX!==mX){
        ellipse(mX,mY,10,10);
    }
    if(pY!==mY){
        ellipse(mX,mY,10,10);
    }
    
    else{
        if (mX >= pX) {
            pX+=1;
            if(pY!==sY){
                if(pY<sY){
                    pY+=1;
                }
                if(pY>sY){
                    pY-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        if (mX < pX) {
            pX-=1;
            if(pY!==sY){
                if(pY<sY){
                    pY+=1;
                }
                if(pY>sY){
                    pY-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        if (mY >= pY) {
            pY+=1;
            if(pX!==sX){
                if(pX<sX){
                    pX+=1;
                }
                if(pX>sX){
                    pX-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    
        if (mY < pY) {
            pY-=1;
            if(pX!==sX){
                if(pX<sX){
                    pX+=1;
                }
                if(pX>sX){
                    pX-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // player(?)
    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    ellipse(pX,pY,10,10);
    
    // borders
    if (pX > 390) {
        pX=390;
    }
    if (pX < 10) {
        pX=10;
    }
    if (pY > 390) {
        pY=390;
    }
    if (pY < 10) {
        pY=10;
    }
    
    // debugging
    noStroke();
    fill(235, 235, 235);
    quad(0,0,75,0,75,140,0,140);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    stroke(255, 0, 0);
    line(tX,tY,mX,mY);
    text("pX = "+pX,10,10);
    text("pY = "+pY,10,25);
    text("test = "+null,10,40);
    text("mX = "+mX,10,55);
    text("mY = "+mY,10,70);
    text("tX = "+tX,10,85);
    text("tY = "+tY,10,100);
    text("sX = "+sX,10,115);
    text("sY = "+sY,10,130);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.7.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your code, such as the set-up code and HTML?  Might make it easier for SO to help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that is all of the code, and I will try to clarify my specific problem.

Comment: Are you trying to "snap" to a grid?

Comment: kind of, but with smooth movements between each grid square? if I understand what you're saying

Comment: I converted this to a runnable snippet by adding the p5.js script and set the canvas size i.e. `setup()`. Shouldn't the `mouseClicked()` function condition be: `(mouseButton === 'left')` ? If you change that like, it looks like it works for the most part.

Comment: Which is it? P5.js, as per how you tagged the question and the CDN link you're showing, or Processing.js, which is what you mention at the start of the post? Because those are completely different libraries.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I accidentally added the Processing tag. OP is using `p5.js`.

Comment: i think my issue is being misunderstood, no, mouseClicked is an inbuilt function in khan academy's special version of processingJS, I don't technically need it because of how I edited the code. My issue is that if you start a new movement while the ellipse is moving, it can get an offset from the center of each grid square. i.e. if you were to start a new movement while the ellipse was not in the center of its current square it would continue moving, not at the center of any square until it reaches its location. I am looking to fix this.

Comment: @Aceae: again though, _which library are we talking about_ because p5js and processing.js are _wildly_ different libraries (and [I archived Processingjs in 2018](https://github.com/processing-js/processing-js#readme), it really shouldn't be used anymore almost 5 years later...)

Comment: KA says that their processingJS is different from the official version, in that they use degrees by default. uses mouseIsPressed instead of mousePressed, likewise it uses keyIsPressed instead of keyPressed. i'm sure there are more differences. I'm using a school Chromebook, and this does not run visual studio code (which is what i'm used to), and instead of trying to find a whole new environment I decided to just use the one that my school uses for programming courses, which is Khan academy.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's an edited version of processing.js used by Khan academy, I don't know if there's an official name other than KA: processingJS.

Comment: also @Mr.Polywhirl changed my code snippet to match p5.js (which I am not familiar with, as I am still new to programming and have only learned khan's processingJS and a smidge of python) and I don't know how or even if I should change it back. The easiest way to view my code is probably with the KA project link but links can be sketchy on the internet and i don't know any other way you could navigate to it, so if you want to view it in the original environment probably just go to khan's no project page and copy paste the code or something.

Comment: @Aceae all I did was make it a runnable snippet. I added the script tag with p5.js and added the `setup()` (size the grid) function. The rest is the same. You said that you were following a ProcessingJS tutorial on Khan Academy. ProcessingJS _is_ p5.js. A snippet just makes it easier for people to visualize your issue. Anyways, I restored your original unaltered code and made the snippet hidden at the end of the question. Also, the link you provided is not publicly-facing. No one can actually view it.

Comment: ah alright, I don't know much about JS as a whole, this year is my first year really messing with it. I believe I thought of a solution, I'm going to test it

Comment: I could not find a solution, so I just changed the movement method. Thanks everyone for trying to help